# Top right and top left corner radius is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cornerradius

i wanted add corner radius for only top corners, when i add corner radius to top corners entire view's width is changing, below is the code which i using.

```
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
     let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
     let mask = CAShapeLayer()
     layer.mask = mask
     mask.path = path.cgPath
     layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

[image: this is happening when add only top corner radius]

when i add corner radius to entire layer it is working fine, [image: this is image when i add corner radius to layer]

layer  view.layer.cornerRadius  = radius

but i want only top corner radius how can i do this without affecting view width

Comment: I just tried your function and it works fine on a standard `UIButton`, but it might be an issue with the button that you are using? It would help if you included the relevant custom button code (How it's layout is built)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function to achieve the behaviour

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: corners,
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = shape
    }
```

and simply use it like this

```
someview.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 25)
```

but the key thing about applying corner radius is when you are applying!! You can apply it in ViewDidAppear or layoutsubviews method. Basically in those places where you are sure about you will get the accurate width and height of the view. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Extension

```
extension UIView 
{

   @discardableResult func _round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
    return mask
   }

func addBorder(mask: CAShapeLayer, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = mask.path
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderLayer.frame = bounds
    layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}

func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let mask = _round(corners: corners, radius: radius)
    addBorder(mask: mask, borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: borderWidth)
}
}
```

And You can call By Below code

```
 self.yourView.round(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 20, borderColor: .clear, borderWidth: 0)
```